# Css justify percentages widths

Tags: css, width, percentage, justify

Just a little question :

```
.site-main .sidebar-container {
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
width:25%;
padding:0px;
margin:0;
border:0;
z-index:2;
float:right;

}
.content-area-sidebar{
width:75%;
display:inline-block;
}
```

why this widths don't work? one of the elemnts always goes down, i need to set 24.79% width to work and then i have a small blank space between them, i have tried with all kind of float combiantions but nothing works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you do a JSFiddle?

Comment: This seems to work in isolation http://jsfiddle.net/w3ZNb/ what browser are you using? and version? your problem is likely caused by other css or html not shown in this example.

Answer (score 0):

set margin:0px to your second css too:

```
.content-area-sidebar{
width:75%;
display:inline-block;
margin:0px;
}
```

by ht way if it doesn't work I suggest you use a div as parent container with position relative and child divs have position absolute so never gets mixed up:

```
<div style="position:relative">
     <div style="width:25%;top:0px;left:0px;position:absolute;"></div>
     <div style="width:75%;top:0px;left:25%;position:absolute;"></div>
</div>
```